# Topology check to close polygon gaps

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, topology

I have a polygon representing a wall.

Is there a topology check on ArcGIS Desktop to close gaps like this? Or is there a different workflow I can try?

[image]

Comment: How was the polygon created?

Answer (score 5):

You could also try tool [Integrate](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/integrate.htm):

> Integrate is used to maintain the integrity of shared feature
>   boundaries by making features coincident if they fall within the
>   specified x,y tolerance. Features that fall within the specified x,y
>   tolerance are considered identical or coincident.

The tool will modify your data so be sure to backup before executing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two idea come to mind:

1) [Snap](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/snap.htm)

[image]

2) [Buffer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm) and negative buffer.

Buffer the polygons by X distance followed by buffering the buffered polygons by -X distance. Make sure to select the dissolve polygons option.

One potentially bad consequence to be aware of with this option is that corners may be rounded the greater the buffer distance.